# Patterns for testing ICommand that call async methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, mvvmcross, icommand

I am just looking at best practices for unit testing (NUnit) [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and specifically the [MvxCommand](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxCommand.cs) implementation within [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross)

**View Model**

```cs
public ICommand GetAuthorisationCommand
{
    get { return new MvxCommand(
            async () => await GetAuthorisationToken(),
            () => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password)); }
}

private async Task GetAuthorisationToken()
{
    // ...Do something async
}
```

**Unit Test**

```cs
[Test]
public async Task DoLogonCommandTest()
{
    //Arrange
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(clubCache, authorisationCache, authorisationService);

    //Act
    await Task.Run(() => vm.GetAuthorisationToken.Execute(null));

    //Assert
    Assert.Greater(MockDispatcher.Requests.Count, 0);
}
```

Now the  problem I have is that the tests drop through with out awaiting the async operations and this feels a little hacky in calling the async method from the ICommand.

Are there any best practices in unit testing these kind of ICommands and async methods?

Comment: As far as I remember you can use the SynchronizationContext to force async command run on the same thread as NUnit, so you'll get synchronous tests of asynchronous methods. But I'm also keen on seeing how others cope with this problem. :)

Comment: @mikes Do you have an example?

Comment: I'd have to look for it. I'll post it when I find the solution. It was something like SynchronousSynchronizationContext iheriting from SynchronizationContext than as instance passed to static method SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `MvxAsyncCommand` (see: [implementation](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/7f39ff87bc7bbb86a0058ea746558875eb196be1/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxAsyncCommand.cs#L171)) instead of `MvxCommand` and change the published type of `GetAuthorisationCommand` from `ICommand` to `IMvxAsyncCommand` (but that interface is **not** available via nuget, yet) and then you can call

```
await vm.GetAuthorisationToken.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Is this available in MVVMCross 3.5.1?

Comment: `MvxAsyncCommand`: yes, `IMvxAsyncCommand`: no (that will be available in the upcomming version). So you have to change the type of `GetAuthorisationCommand` to `MvxAsyncCommand`

Comment: Just opened the version referenced in the PCL with JustDecompile and MVxAsyncCommand is not present within the Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels namespace. This PCL was downloaded via Nuget.

Comment: Ohh :/ I just looked at the 3.5 branch on github. Maybe it's in an newer release or they just worked on 4.0 on this branch for a while :/ https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels

Comment: Looked at the same, it does say the initial commit was Apr 24, 2015 but it's not in the 3.5.1 assembly

Comment: It is available in 3.5.2-alpha2. So you have to go for alpha or update to 4 :)

Comment: I took the code from GitHub and implemented it into v3.5.1 and it appears to work. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

I think [the answer with `MvxAsyncCommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36867423/263693) is the best long-term solution.

However, if you want something that works today without depending on prerelease software, you can follow this pattern [which I have found helpful when dealing with asynchronous MVVM commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

First, define an `IAsyncCommand`:

```
interface IAsyncCommand: ICommand
{
  Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}
```

Then you can define an `AsyncCommand` implementation as such:

```
public class AsyncCommand: MvxCommand, IAsyncCommand
{
  private readonly Func<Task> _execute;

  public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute)
      : this(execute, null)
  {
  }

  public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
      : base(async () => await execute(), canExecute)
  {
    _execute = execute;
  }

  public Task ExecuteAsync()
  {
    _execute();
  }
}
```

And then use `await command.ExecuteAsync()` instead of `command.Execute()` in your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

As a command is a fire and forget event you dont get back a completion directly. 
I would suggest splitting the test into two actions (or even creating two Unit test).

1. Test if the Command can be executed
2. Test if the Async Task return expected result

Something along the lines of:

```
//Act
var canExecute = vm.GetAuthorisationToken.CanExecute();
var result = await vm.GetAuthorisationToken();
```

However, is would require `GetAuthorisationToken` to change its protection level from private inorder to expose it for the unit test.

**Alternatively**

You can make use of a library such as [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), which can allow you to await the completion of the async call.

```
[Test]
public async Task DoLogonCommandTest()
{
    AsyncContext.Run(() =>
    {
        //Arrange
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(clubCache, authorisationCache, authorisationService);

        //Act
        await Task.Run(() => vm.GetAuthorisationToken.Execute(null));
    });

    //Assert
    Assert.Greater(MockDispatcher.Requests.Count, 0);
}
```